# Single server, single IP, mail with other services -- do I need a mail subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, reverse-dns

I have a server with a single IP configured to act as a mail server and to provide other services (e.g. http).

DNS records are like:

```
mail.example.com A 192.0.2.4
example.com MX mail.example.com
```

and a PTR record `192.0.2.4 -> mail.example.com` for FCrDNS spam checks.

However, since the server is not just a mail server, it is odd to have the rDNS for `192.0.2.4` point to `mail.example.com`. The way I understand it, there is no way around this if my server sends `HELO mail.example.com`. Is there any downside then to eliminating the `mail` subdomain completely so I can use a more general PTR `192.0.2.4 -> example.com`?

I have no other local organizational/institutional constraints that, to me, might provide an obvious "yes" to that question, but I'd seemingly be diverging from the standard convention that mail for `foo.example` is sent from `mail.foo.example`. (I know the name `mail` is not magical, but I wonder if I really need any subdomain at all.)

And since FCrDNS is for sending mail and `MX` is for receiving, to keep things congruent, would there be anything wrong with an MX record like `example.com MX example.com`?

Comment: "I'd seemingly be diverging from the standard convention that mail for foo.example is sent from mail.foo.example. " There is no reasons for that at all the `mail` prefix is often chosen to depict where email is sent TO, that is as an `MX` record. Where mail is sent FROM is completely separate (can be completely separate), and will be controlled by SPF records.

Comment: `example.com MX example.com` you can have that technically but then as you will need an `A`/`AAAA`  record for the name, you could even live without the `MX` one because SMTP has clear fallback on direct `A`/`AAAA` if no `MX` is found. Might not be 100% wise to rely on that fallback but it is what the specification says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any name for your mailer system, provided your DNS setup is consistent. There is no such convention that mail should be managed by "mail.example.com", and actually most services don't even bother to get near this convention (check `host -t mx gmail.com` for an example). It just happened *convenient* for small mail system to be laid out like that.

`example.com MX 10 example.com` is perfectly correct MX record (don't forget the "priority" field). As it is mentioned in comments, it's redundant, but if you are going to set up SPF record as "v=spf1 mx -", you need the MX record.

Using a separate name may make migration easier in the future, however, if you decide to move your mail system.

Comment: How might it make migration easier?

Comment: No need to change configuration of clients who already using that separate name. Just servers and DNS records of that name will need to be reconfigured.